Copy ChronicleChannel wire to 2 Appender
i copied wire to 2 appender, and read 2nd appender after copy.
after read, 1st appender data is fail to do something.
i expect copyTo is whole data. The copy data with work independent.
    try (DocumentContext dc2 = pub.appender.writingDocument()) {
        dc.wire().copyTo(dc2.wire());                               
    }
                            
    try(DocumentContext dcallw = puball.appender.writingDocument()){                                
        dc.wire().copyTo(dcallw.wire());
    }
                            
    try(DocumentContext dcallr = puball.tailer.readingDocument()){
        String ss = dcallr.wire().readEvent(String.class);
    }

